# Pythonic way to use persistent telnet connection?

Tags: python, class, reference, telnet

I'm trying to write a Python (3.3, if it makes a difference) class that will communicate with a modem over a telnet connection. Basically, different commands will be sent to the modem depending on user input, and I'd like to keep the telnet connection open during the execution of the program. It's probably worth noting that it's my first time working with Python, having come from a C# and Java background, so I'm still trying to get the hang of it.

Anyways, I guess I haven't learned that much about OO concepts, so I was going to ask this: is there a preferred way to re-use a persistent telnet connection in multiple methods in the same class? Also, would it be advisable to put the code current in `_login` in `__init__`? I'll give some code examples:

### Option A: pass `tn` to `_login`

```
class Communicator:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet()

    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password):
        self._login(user, password)

    def _login(self, host, port, user, password, conn=tn):
        conn.open(host, port)
        conn.read_until("Username: ")
        conn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
        conn.read_until("Password: ")
        conn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
```

### Option B: have `_login` use `self.tn`

```
class Communicator:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet()

    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password):
        self._login(user, password)

    def _login(self, host, port, user, password):
        self.tn.open(host, port)
        self.tn.read_until("Username: ")
        self.tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
        self.tn.read_until("Password: ")
        self.tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
```

### Option C: something else?

I'm always open to suggestions. Like I said, this is my first time playing around with Python and I should practice the Pythonic way of doing things.

Comment: Why are you using double underscores ([name mangling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)) in front of `login`?

Comment: @gnibbler I meant it to be one underscore, thanks for pointing that out.